# Change font color for specific char in a cell range

Tags: excel, vba, character

I would like to change the font color for a specific character within a range of cells. I figured out how to do this for a single cell (code attached), but I can't figure out how to do it over a full range of cells; B8: F12. Can anyone help?

thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim FindChar As String
Dim SearchString As String

SearchString = Range("B8").Value
FindChar = Chr(182)

For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
    If Mid(SearchString, i, 1) = FindChar Then
        Range("B8").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(221, 221, 221)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ChangeColorIfMatchesCondition(byval cell as Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim FindChar As String
Dim SearchString As String

SearchString = cell.Value
FindChar = Chr(182)

For i = 1 To Len(SearchString)
    If Mid(SearchString, i, 1) = FindChar Then
        cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(221, 221, 221)
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub LoopAndChangeColorForThisRange()
dim cell

dim targetRange as Range
set targetRange = me.Range("B8:F12")

for each cell in targetRange.Cells
   ChangeColorIfMatchesCondition cell
next
End Sub
```

Make a call to `LoopAndChangeColorForThisRange` and see if it works, as you'd expect.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the fast reply.