# Search text string for a match and change font color

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

It's been 6 years since I've worked with Excel and i'm a little bit rusty. Here's my scenario:

I am exporting a list of issues to Excel. I need to be able differentiate the associated Link numbers in a cell (mulitple values) from each other. Example, i have two columns,

Key = the number for a ticket

Linked Issues = The Keys associated

I need a statement that would scan the Key column and find a match in the Linked Issues column. Then once the match is found the matching text will assume the font color of the Key.

Where this get complicated is each cell of the Linked Issues column could look something like this iss-3913, iss-3923, iss-1649. So essentially the scan would be for a match within the string. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to have one cell with multiple font colors in it? Also, tell me this: does the first column have "iss-3913" and the second column have "3923, 1649, 8352" for example? Or does the second column also have "iss-3923, iss-1649, iss-8352"?

Comment: So Cell "A1" contains a single value iss-3715 and is color red (all values in column A are uniquie). Multiple cells in column Z contain iss-3715 in the string of linked issues eg. iss-2190, iss-2222, iss-3715, iss-9000 in one cell. I want to be able to have matching pieces of the string to inherit the font color of it's match in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I am sorry, I don't have time to finish this right now, but w</del>Would something like this help <del>with maybe a loop for each cell in the first column</del>?

**Edit**: Finished now, second edit to update to B5 and Z5, edit 3 fixed goof with column reference and updated to use variables to assign what column to look in.

```
Sub colortext()
start_row = 5
key_col = 2
linked_col = 26
i = start_row 'start on row one
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, key_col)) 'Do until empty cell
    o = start_row 'start with row one for second column
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(o, linked_col)) 'Do until empty cell
    If Not InStr(1, Cells(o, linked_col), Cells(i, key_col)) = 0 Then  'if cell contents found in cell
        With Cells(o, linked_col).Characters(Start:=InStr(1, Cells(o, linked_col), Cells(i, key_col)), Length:=Len(Cells(i, key_col))).Font
            .Color = Cells(i, key_col).Font.Color  'change color of this part of the cell
        End With
    End If
    o = o + 1 'increment the cell in second column
    Loop
    i = i + 1 'increment the cell in the first column
Loop
End Sub
```

or maybe

Something like this?

[Excel VBA: change font color for specific char in a cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759962/excel-vba-change-font-color-for-specific-char-in-a-cell-range)

Comment: Awesome. This just what I was looking for! If my key (row1/cell1) starts at Row 2/cell5 (B5) and my linked issues are in row 26 (Z$) what fields do I manipulate?

Comment: @user2642587 I updated the code. i is the starting "key" row. o is the starting "linked issues" row. Everywhere you see Cells(i,2) the two represents the column for the "key". Everywhere you see Cells(o,26) the 26 represents the column for the "linked issues". Good luck.

Comment: Actually this does not change anything in column 26.

Comment: okay it works as long as my key in column A but the export names the project in that field. Let me make some changes.

Comment: @user2642587 Okay, sorry about that last update, I found a goof when I converted the columns, so I made them variables and you can change start row and columns now. A little FYI if you didn't notice, these loops will stop if there is an empty cell between your data. I was assuming there wasn't any. Good luck.

Comment: Actually all Keys do not have associated Links. The code ran unitil the empty space in column 26. I added some code to fill those blanks before the colortext code but now the blanks are filled and all matching links are blue (hyperlink color). I removed the hyperlinks before copying the export but the other colors never make it to column 26. I don't know where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Sub Main() 
SetCellWarning 
colortext 
End Sub 

Sub SetCellWarning() 
Dim iLastRow As Long 
Dim cel As Range, rSetColumn As Range 
iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 

Set rSetColumn = Range(Cells(5, 26), Cells(iLastRow, 26)) 

For Each cel In rSetColumn If cel.Value = "" Then 
With cel cel.Value = "NOT MAPPED" 
End With 
End If 
Next cel 
End Sub

Comment: @user2642587 Aren't you working in B, or 2, column but you have (Rows.Count, 1), instead of (Rows.Count, 2)? Changing this worked for me.

Comment: I removed the code to alter the blank cells in the linked_col and nothing is happening. It runs but nothing is updated. Prior to the update I would at least get the first few fields to update.

Comment: I noticed the colors in column B are all black when I open up the format. Could it be that the code isn't working because the colors in B are conditionally formatted to change color based on the value od D. This is odd.

Comment: Okay so apparently this is a very importment piece that I left out. The cell colors in the key column are being changed by conditional formatting. So if column D has the text "Requirement" the key in that row will be displayed in green. I just learned that this only changes the display appearance not the actual color. When I manually change the colors the code works perfectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2642587 Yes sir. It gets hairy now, and unfortunately, it is beyond my experience to check the conditional formatting. If you can check all the conditions such as, "Requirement" in column D, and then correlate that to the appropriate cell in column B, and then update column Z, that may work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I thought I would provide my work around to the conditional formating issue I was having.

```
Sub colorkey()
start_row = 5
key_col = 2
flag_col = 4

i = start_row 'start on row one

  Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, key_col)) 'Do until empty cell

  Tval = Cells(i, flag_col).Value
    Select Case Tval
    Case "Requirement"
        'cval = green
        cVal = 10
    Case "New Feature"
        'cval = orange
        cVal = 46
    Case "Test"
        'cval = lt blue
        cVal = 28
    Case "Epic"
        'cval = maroon
        cVal = 30
    Case "Story"
        'cval = dk blue
        cVal = 49
    Case "Theme"
        'cval = grey
        cVal = 48
    Case "Bug"
        'cval = red
        cVal = 3
    Case "NOT MAPPED"
        'cval = Maroon
        cVal = 1
    End Select


Cells(i, key_col).Font.ColorIndex = cVal

    i = i + 1 'increment the cell in the first column
    Loop

End Sub
Sub colorlinked()
start_row = 5
key_col = 2
linked_col = 26
i = start_row 'start on row one
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, key_col)) 'Do until empty cell
    o = start_row 'start with row one for second column
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(o, linked_col)) 'Do until empty cell
    If Not InStr(1, Cells(o, linked_col), Cells(i, key_col)) = 0 Then  'if cell contents found in cell
        With Cells(o, linked_col).Characters(Start:=InStr(1, Cells(o, linked_col), Cells(i, key_col)), Length:=Len(Cells(i, key_col))).Font
            .Color = Cells(i, key_col).Font.Color  'change color of this part of the cell
        End With
    End If
    o = o + 1 'increment the cell in second column
    Loop
    i = i + 1 'increment the cell in the first column
Loop
MsgBox "Finished Scanning"
End Sub
```