# Change text color according to character value in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've an excel sheet of numerous fields where one column includes Japanese characters, here's a sampling of a few rows...

コク, きざ-む
サイ, つま
ザン, のこ-る, のこ-す
シ, ゆび, さ-す
ド, つと-める

I'd like to have all Katakana characters displaying in one colour, while Hiragana in another, and if possible the hiragana characters following a dash in yet another.

For example... (コク, サイ, ザン, シ, ド) would be coloured green, while (きざ, つま, のこ, のこ, ゆび, さ, つと) would be coloured blue, and.. (む, る, す, す, す, める) would be coloured purple if possible, otherwise blue just as with the rest of the Hiragana if not. As for the commas/dashes.. I'm not fussed about their colour or whether deleted etc.

Note: While each line (cell) listed begins with katakana and ends in hiragana this is not always the case within my full range of data, as occasionally the hiragana will be first, or.. it'll be a line exclusive of either hiragana or katakana.

So how would I go about automating the text formatting as shown..? I assume VBA would be neceessary.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759962/excel-vba-change-font-color-for-specific-char-in-a-cell-range) might give you a good idea of how to start. You'll need to identify which character value ranges correspond to the hiragana/katakana you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that will do what you want if your data is in A1:A5 of the first sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorJapanese()
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Dim range As Excel.range
    Set range = sheet.range(sheet.Cells(1, 1), sheet.Cells(5, 1))

    Dim cell As Excel.range
    Dim font As Excel.font
    Dim i&, value&
    Dim dashFound As Boolean
    For Each cell In range
        dashFound = False
        For i = 1 To cell.Characters.Count
            Set font = cell.Characters(i, 1).font
            value = AscW(cell.Characters(i, 1).Text)
            If IsHirangana(value) Then
                If dashFound Then
                    font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)
                Else
                    font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                End If
            ElseIf IsKatakana(value) Then
                font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ElseIf value = AscW("-") Then
                dashFound = True
            Else
                dashFound = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function IsHirangana(value&) As Boolean
    If value >= CInt("&H" & "3041") And value <= CInt("&H" & "3094") Then
        IsHirangana = True
    Else
        IsHirangana = False
    End If
End Function

Function IsKatakana(value&) As Boolean
    If value >= CInt("&H" & "30A1") And value <= CInt("&H" & "30FB") Then
        IsKatakana = True
    Else
        IsKatakana = False
    End If
End Function
```

Next time show what you have done so far and where you struggled. People here will not write your code for you (unless they are bored at lunchbreak :p).