# Detect difference between cells where text is the same but text formatting differs

Tags: excel, vba

I want to detect if anything about the text is different between two cells.

For example, cells A1 and B1 have the same text but different formatting of the text:

> Cell A1:  This is my cell.
>
> Cell B1:  This <s>**is my**</s> cell.

The following code does not flag a difference:

```
'if the text in the cells is different in any way, report a difference
If (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "A") <> ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "B")) Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "C").Value = DIFFERENT
End If
```

Comment: you are not checking the formatting with that code, you are checking to see if the values are the same.  You will need to loop through each character in the cell and check the formatting and compare that way.  This should get you going in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759962/change-font-color-for-specific-char-in-a-cell-range

Comment: Are you checking for differences in size/color, or just certain things like italic/bold/strikethrough?

Comment: Italic/bold/strike through and colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether comparing the cells' .Value(11) XML code will catch every discrepancy you are looking for but it does catch the differences in your example strings' formatting.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print .Cells(1, "A").Value(11)
    Debug.Print .Cells(1, "B").Value(11)
    If .Cells(1, "A").Value(11) <> .Cells(1, "B").Value(11) Then
      .Cells(1, "C").Value = "DIFFERENT"
    End If
End With
```

For the unformated cell this element is pretty plain.

```
...
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">abcdef</Data></Cell>
...
```

Not so for the one formatted with bold and strike-through characters.

```
...
<Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font
   html:Color="#000000">ab</Font><B><S><Font html:Size="8.8000000000000007"
     html:Color="#000000">cde</Font></S></B><Font html:Color="#000000">f</Font></ss:Data></Cell>
...
```

To compare only that <Cell> element,

```
Dim val11A As String, val11B As String

With ActiveSheet
    val11A = Split(Split(.Cells(1, "A").Value(11), "<Cell>")(1), "</Cell>")(0)
    val11B = Split(Split(.Cells(1, "B").Value(11), "<Cell>")(1), "</Cell>")(0)
    If val11A <> val11B Then
      .Cells(1, "C").Value = "DIFFERENT"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: New one for me...   It does seem to include a lot of properties such as alignment/borders etc which might not be required

Comment: Yeah, either it's appropriate or it's not; I'll let the OP decide. Be a shame if not as it is a quick and easy method of getting character differences without looping through each char in the string and comparing many formatting properties..

Comment: Ran into some issues with the front side of the split because most of my Cell XML was coming back with a StyleID attribute - e.g.,  "<Cell ss:StyleID="s153">" - so I changed the front side of the split to be just "<Cell".

Answer (score 3):

e.g:

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print SameText(Range("B4"), Range("C4"))
End Sub

'call from VBA or as UDF
Function SameText(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Boolean
    Dim rv As Boolean, c1, c2, x As Long, arr, v

    If rng1.Value = rng2.Value Then
        rv = True
        arr = Array("Underline", "Fontstyle", "Color") '<< for example
        For x = 1 To Len(rng1.Value)
            Set c1 = rng1.Characters(x, 1).Font
            Set c2 = rng2.Characters(x, 1).Font
            For Each v In arr
                If CallByName(c1, v, VbGet) <> CallByName(c2, v, VbGet) Then
                    Debug.Print "Mismatch on " & v & " at position " & x, _
                                 rng1.Address, rng2.Address
                    rv = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
        Next x
    Else
        rv = False
    End If

    SameText = rv
End Function
```

Comment: This solution worked too - but it was slower than the Value(11) solution.  If only doing one Font property, this solution was .3x slower than the Value(11) solution (operating on ~3000 rows).  If doing four Font properties, it was >2.5x slower and I killed the macro before letting it finish. <CAVEAT> I changed the algorithm from using .Range to using .Cells to access a single cell because it was barfing on my call to .Range and I didn't have time to investigate and I only needed to compare a single cell anyways.  I also did not put the algorithm a function, I defined it within a loop.