# Change Excel cell text color using VBA in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a problem with changing the color of text in a cell in an Excel worksheet using Access VBA. (I'm formatting my Excel within Access VBA then I export the Excel file)

I want to change only the color for the first 5 Characters in a cell. I've tried using the following code:

```
ws.Cells(18, 6).Characters(1, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
```

But in the result (after Export) all of the characters in that cell will be changed (length of the cell is 68).

I dont understand where the problem is in the code. Maybe I need to use a different function to `.Characters` for changing the color?

Could someone please help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font color for specific char in a cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759962/change-font-color-for-specific-char-in-a-cell-range)

Comment: in Excel with vba its possible, but apparently with the same Code in Access vba its not possible

Comment: no it's possible - but what happens here I suspect, is that the export is messing it up. Run the format after the export rather than before.

Comment: @HarassedDad thank you man you are my hero :D its worked after Export, if i open the workbook and Formate it then